# Gulp not detecting file changes in subfolder

Tags: docker, gulp, yeoman

I'm using a [docker-yeoman image](https://github.com/cthulhu666/docker-yeoman) to launch a container and then running the Yeoman gulp-webapp generator to generate a project skeleton.

Once generated, I'm running it in the same container using:

```
docker run -it -p 9000:9000 -p 35729:35729 --rm -v $(pwd):/src cthulhu666/yeoman:gulp gulp serve`
```

This bit is all working fine. I can view the site by visiting 192.168.99.100:9000 (I'm using Docker Toolbox so it's a VM rather than localhost).

But something strange is happening:

If I add `body { background: red; }` to **/app/styles/main.scss**, the change is detected by Gulp, the tasks are run and the background of the page goes red. So far so good.

However, if I then create a **/app/styles/partials/_test.scss** and then move the body selector into that file (including it in main.scss with `import "partials/test";`) then no changes are detected by Gulp when I save the file. The only way I can get it to "notice" the changes is to re-save the main.scss file, at which point Gulp kicks in and the changes to the _test.scss file are also applied.

I tested this by installing the generator locally and re-running the same experiment. Sure enough, the changes are applied just fine when made in either main.scss and _test.scss, as expected.

Can anyone shed any light on why this isn't the case in the Docker container?

Comment: use glob syntax, something like: `sass/**/*.scss`.

Comment: It's already using that in the gulpfile: `gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);` 

It does seem to pick up subdirectory changes when run locally with the exact same configuration... just something about being in a Docker container that causes issues with the underscores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be something to do with the underscore in the filename. SCSS allows you to use an variety of naming conventions:

Filename: **/partials/_test.scss** /
SCSS: @import "partials/_test";

Filename: **/partials/_test.scss** /
SCSS: @import "partials/test";

Filename: **/partials/test.scss** /
SCSS: @import "partials/test";

All three of the above import the partial correctly. However, only the last allows Gulp to detect changes (though only in a Docker container - it works fine locally).

I'd still be interested to know why this is, if anyone has any ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox shared folders don't work very well with file watching.

- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10660
- https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/707

(I'm sure you can find many others)

Virtualbox is what is being used by Docker Toolbox/Docker Machine to provide the VM.